# grid-template-columns is not applied with a list of items

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to implement a list component with the grid layout, which got some sub components for filtering, etc. The problem is, the items get pushed into a third column, even though I only declared two in the `grid-template-columns` rule.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  margin: 50px;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  place-items: stretch;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: 
   "dropdown dropdown" 
   "filter   ." 
   "filter   ." 
   "breaker  breaker";
}

.dropdown {
  grid-area: dropdown;
  background-color: red;
}

.filter {
  grid-area: filter;
  background-color: green;
}

.breaker {
  grid-area: breaker;
  background-color: blue;
}

.item {
  background-color: orange;
}

.pagination {
  grid-column: 1 / end;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">Dropdown </div>
  <div class="filter">Filter </div>
  <div class="breaker">Breaker </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="pagination">Pagination </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c0y1bmza/7/

Comment: Declaring only two columns doesn't mean there can only be two columns. If grid areas are placed outside of those two columns, new columns will be created for them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `grid-column: 1 / end;` and you didn't define any area called `end` so you are creating a new column in the implicit grid to have 3 columns (2 explicitely defined and 1 implicit)

Use `-1` instead:

> If a negative integer is given, it instead counts in reverse, starting from **the end** edge of the **explicit grid**. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#line-placement)</sup>

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  margin: 50px;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  place-items: stretch;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: 
   "dropdown dropdown" 
   "filter   ." 
   "filter   ." 
   "breaker  breaker";
}

.dropdown {
  grid-area: dropdown;
  background-color: red;
}

.filter {
  grid-area: filter;
  background-color: green;
}

.breaker {
  grid-area: breaker;
  background-color: blue;
}

.item {
  background-color: orange;
}

.pagination {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">Dropdown </div>
  <div class="filter">Filter </div>
  <div class="breaker">Breaker </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="pagination">Pagination </div>
</div>
```

Or `breaker-end` (or `drowpdown-end`) for this case:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  margin: 50px;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  place-items: stretch;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: 
   "dropdown dropdown" 
   "filter   ." 
   "filter   ." 
   "breaker  breaker";
}

.dropdown {
  grid-area: dropdown;
  background-color: red;
}

.filter {
  grid-area: filter;
  background-color: green;
}

.breaker {
  grid-area: breaker;
  background-color: blue;
}

.item {
  background-color: orange;
}

.pagination {
  grid-column: 1 / breaker-end;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">Dropdown </div>
  <div class="filter">Filter </div>
  <div class="breaker">Breaker </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="item">Item </div>
  <div class="pagination">Pagination </div>
</div>
```

> The `grid-template-areas` property creates implicit named lines from the named grid areas in the template. For each named grid area *foo*, four implicit named lines are created: two named *foo-start*, naming the row-start and column-start lines of the named grid area, and two named *foo-end*, naming the row-end and column-end lines of the named grid area. <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#implicit-named-lines)</sup>

Comment: thanks for the fast and detailed answer! Seems, like I misunderstood the `end` keyword here, but your post makes the usage clear